How does DHCP work on a direct ethernet link between hosts?
I plugged in an ethernet cable between my desktop and laptop for faster, direct, file transfer. Both run Linux Mint, and both are connected to the same WiFi (probably WiFi is irrelevant here). Both have only dhcp client package installed but, AFAICT from dpkg -l, neither has dhcp server installed. Yet, each managed to configure 10.0.0.1 and .2 by itself without any prodding. How does this work, without any dhcp server installed? Which host initiates the connection, and how do they negotiate and reach consensus? dmesg only tells me the link is up but nothing much else.

You say WiFi is irrelevant, but then say they are connected to WiFi.  Are you sure the IPs are not assigned by the WiFi router?

Does Mint use NetworkManager? If so, can you show the output of nmcli con in terminal?

It could be APIPA, but those usually start with 169.254.

Please clarify your question. You say your system is connected by WiFi instead of an Ethernet connection then say WiFi is probably irrelevant. All operating systems typically handle Ethernet adapters and WiFi adapters independently, and thus their configuration, are separate independent
